# Как посчитать количество элементов в массиве отличных от null. php

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь посчитать количество элементов в массиве отличных от null и сравнить это число с числом 5.  Ниже привожу код

```js
<?
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_DATE_VISIT");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => "14", "ACTIVE" => "Y", "?PROPERTY_DATE_VISIT" => "04.2018");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize" => 300), $arSelect);
while ($ob = $res->Fetch()) {
    $result[] = $ob['ID'];
}
//echo var_dump($result);
$value = array();
$peremen = array();
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $model = new evraz3;
    $data = $model->loadRestorePass2(1, $value);
    $firstname = $data["PROPERTY"]["VISITOR"][0]["UF_FIRSTNAME"];
    var_dump($firstname);
 }
```

В массиве $firstname содержится следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

> Как посчитать количество элементов в массиве отличных от null

В вашем коде, честно, сказать не видно, где вы и что пытаетесь посчитать.
Но для фильтрации `null` (и подобных) элементов можно использовать функцию `array_filter`, а для подсчета оставшихся - `count`.

```
 $notNullCount = count(array_filter($firstname));
```

Если же требуется отфильтровать исключительно `null`-значения (без `0`, `false`, `''` и т.п.) то можно либо написать соответствующую callback-функцию для фильтрации, либо использовать `array_reduce()`, либо обойтись простым циклом со сравнением.

Comment: Спасибо, за ваш ответ, буду пробывать!